# DELETE VALIDATION for DataGridView

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, delete-row

I wan't some help about my DELETE button.
At first my the code was a success. It can delete both the data's from the vb program as well as the data of the database which is located at MS Access.

But, when I added some validations to my DELETE button, adding it some MessageBoxstyle and MessageBoxButton it just won't work. It only deletes the entry of the textboxes not the data itself.

My Question Would be...

I wan't my program to not only DELETE the data on the textboxes but also the data that corresponds on the DatagridView when I press "YES" on the confirmation message. And when I click on the NO button it'll only just remain as it is. HOW do you do this???

Please someone help me. I'm new to this and still learning. I'm still a student and I really need this for my System... thank you!

Here is my code!

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Monitoring_Form

```
Dim connect As OleDbConnection
Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim commnd As OleDbCommand
Dim dataset As DataSet
Dim datatable As DataTable
Dim table As DataTableCollection
Dim binding As New BindingSource
Dim id As Integer
Dim Email As Boolean


Private Sub btn_cdelete_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_cdelete.Click
    txt_customerID.Text = id




    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wan't to DELETE this record?", "Delete Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

        commnd = New OleDbCommand("delete  FROM CustomersInfo WHERE FirstName = '" + txt_firstname.Text + "'", connect)
        commnd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("ENTRY SUCCESSFULLY DELETED!")

        txt_customerID.Text = ""
        txt_firstname.Text = ""
        txt_lastname.Text = ""
        txt_add.Text = ""
        txt_cnumber.Text = ""
        txt_email.Text = ""

        '' Me.dgv_1.Rows.RemoveAt(Me.dgv_1.CurrentRow.ToString())







    Else

    End If






End Sub
```

I've just edited my Question to make it clear for you guys. Please help and sorry for the mistake.

This is the revision of my code

Comment: You didnt ask a question or even describe a problem.  Are we to assume that the code is deleting even if you click the NO button?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: No, if you click on the NO button it will only remain as it is. Just the YES button. 

Sorry for the mistake. Just new and this was my first time writing this code problem of mine.

Comment: Test **and debug** your code.  Since you have nothing in the `Else` portion it should do nothing if you click 'No'.

Comment: Done that already and the result I get was still the same. I think my problem is on the YES part. Cause if I click it, it still won't able to delete the records of my DataGridView has.

Comment: There still **is not a clear problem statement anywhere**.  Is it *not* deleting or *always* deleting?  Where is that code snippet located?  We have no context for it.  Part of what you are saying cannot be true - the `MessageBox` is not going to return Yes if you press No.  Set a breakpoint  (**debug**) and see if it executes the delete code even when you press No and vice versa

Comment: You are making a bold assumption on the line `MsgBox("ENTRY SUCCESSFULLY DELETED!")`… Without checking if the deletion was successful, your message is dubious at best. It is not clear what `txt_firstname.Text` contains... however, if the user is able to type into this text box then there is a good chance it will be wrong. In that case, following the code, the delete will fail in the delete to the database, since there is no check for this failure, the code will prompt the user that the deletion succeeded, and then proceed to delete all the text in text boxes.